# How to:customise the django Usercreationform Errors

Tags: django

I make a login and registration system with Usercreationform but whenever the user enters some wrong data it appears as normal black text under the field which had an error which doesn't really catch the users attention. How can I edit the html in the error message to make the error red or something like that.

Comment: Can you show what have you try

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django-Crispy-Form, it will [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) automagicaly your form so the error and form will looks better with almost no effort.

Here is how to add it to your project:

Installing django-crispy-forms

Install latest stable version into your python path using pip or easy_install:

```
pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms
```

Add crispy_forms to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
)
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

in your HTML header don't forget to include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And a the end of the body:

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then if you.want to use it simply load the tag and add |crispy after your form (in the html) like:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

And for the refrence the project documentation : https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And a tutorial about it: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial on how to render forms manually](http://%20https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html)

And to be specific how to render errors in red color.

```
{% if field.errors %}
   <ul style="list-style-type: none; color:red">
   {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```